# Maven 'versions' plugin not picking up properties from parent

Tags: maven-2

I don't know if I'm missing something, but I have a problem with the Codehaus [versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) for Maven. Here's a simplification of my situation:

- root:

  - moduleA
  - moduleB

'root' is an aggregator POM, i.e. declaring moduleA and moduleB as child *modules*, and A and B both have root as *parent*.

Both A and B have a dependency on *project-C*, but the **version** of this dependency is defined in a **property** - say `<project-C.version>` - not hardcoded. This property is defined in *root*, so both A and B inherit the same version value for project-C.

In root POM:

```
<properties>
    <project-C.version>1.0</project-C.version>
```

In module A and B (remember *root* is parent):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.blah</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-C</artifactId>
    <version>${project-C.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, say newer version 1.1-SNAPSHOT of project-C becomes available. I want to use the *versions* plugin to show this to me, so I run:

```
$ cd /projects/root
$ mvn versions:display-property-updates -DallowSnapshots=true
```

but all I get is something like this:

```
[INFO] Building root  
[INFO] This project does not have any properties associated with versions

[INFO] Building moduleA  
[INFO] This project does not have any properties associated with versions

[INFO] Building moduleB  
[INFO] This project does not have any properties associated with versions
```

It doesn't make a difference if I run it on root, moduleA or moduleB: it always says that. Of course it works if I hardcode project-C's version number in the dependencies.

So, in summary: I want to centralise dependency versions as properties in a root (aggregator/parent) POM, and I want the *versions* plugin to pick those up for goals that work on properties, i.e.:

- display-property-updates
- update-properties

How do I do this? Am I missing something? Is this a bug in versions plugin?

Comment: As a heads up, think this issue was solved meanwhile.
At least I didn't have to jump through those hoops, with `org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1`.

(and i did have to do it in my older build code :-) )

Comment: Thanks @tobi42. Yeah, it's 11 years later, good to know they fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the answer you received in [MVERSIONS-123](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-123) is not accurate:

> If the properties are defined in the parent pom, then run the goal from the parent pom (including the child projects as part of the aggregator if necessary in order to pick up the dependencies)

This part is not true, or at least doesn't occur. It seems the versions plugin only look or properties in the current pom. Declaring the following in the parent does work:

```
<properties>
    <project-C.version>1.0</project-C.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.blah</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-C</artifactId>
    <version>${project-C.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But declaring the property in the parent and the dependency in the child doesn't (even when running the plugin on the parent).

Now, if the behavior described by Stephen in [MVERSIONS-123](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-123) is the expected behavior, then there is a bug (and you should actually provide a simple project allowing to reproduce, I did a simple test with Junit as dependency).

But in your case (it was maybe just an example though) since both A and B depend on C, why don't you put C in the parent? This would work. You should use `dependencyManagement` anyway (and this will work if you don't want to inherit it everywhere).

Comment: Thanks, @Pascal. I suspect it's a bug in the plugin, as you succinctly put it: 'But declaring the property in the parent and the dependency in the child doesn't (even when running the plugin on the parent).' 

I'll knock up an example and add it to MVERSIONS-123.

I'll switch to the `dependencyManagement` solution now.

Comment: @Cornel I agree. And uploading a sample demo project will certainly increase the chances to get the issue reopened. There is something wrong.

Comment: Any update on this? The link the issue is broken and I'm still experiencing this.

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to be a job for dependencyManagement section in your root pom...

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering that, but it will be much more verbose than the property solution.